# OpenStreetMap data missing between online map and database

Tags: openstreetmap

The Great Britain data `(.osm.pbf)` downloaded from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html and loaded into `PostGIS` database. I figured out there are some missing data in the downloaded database compared to what you see on https://www.openstreetmap.org/.

A few examples are - [92344357](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/92344357) (Edited about 1 year ago), [151507677](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/151507677) (Edited 3 months ago).

Any possible reasons for this?

Comment: How did you verify that these two objects are missing in your database?

Comment: I used  the node id `select * from  public.osm_nodes where id='151507677'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`151507677` and `92344357` are *ways*, not *nodes*. Instead of `osm_nodes` you have to search for them in `osm_ways`.

See [OSM elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) for an explanation of the basic OSM elements, i.e. nodes, ways and relations.